# Pivot_Longer based on column value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

And I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
team                    points 
chicago_fire            1.725424    
Club de Foot Montreal   1.0349628   
Chicago Fire            1.16111572
Columbus Crew            1.591609
.
.
.
```

Which would mean using `pivot_longer` selectively.

My code at the moment is as so:

```
expected_points <- simulate_results %>%
                  mutate(home_expected_points= 3* home_win_prob + 1* draw_prob, away_expected_points = 3* away_win_prob + 1* draw_prob) %>%
                  select(home,away, away_expected_points,home_expected_points) %>%
                  pivot_longer(,cols = c("home","away","away_expected_points","home_expected_points"), values_to = 'points',names_to = 'type')
expected_points
```

but I get an error from mixing the double and character values of the df. Is this something that such be done in one step ?

Here is the head of the df just before the pivot:

```
structure(list(home = c("Chicago Fire", "Chicago Fire", "Chicago Fire", 
"Chicago Fire", "Chicago Fire", "Chicago Fire"), away = c("Club de Foot Montreal", 
"Columbus Crew", "DC United", "Houston Dynamo", "Los Angeles Galaxy", 
"New England Revolution"), away_expected_points = c(1.03496281825711, 
1.16115715218849, 1.07116563833606, 1.09794662072245, 1.50393127764973, 
1.22115923847215), home_expected_points = c(1.72542415785488, 
1.59160932991963, 1.67152015760113, 1.64871325211506, 1.25278573638545, 
1.52350845382982)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    home = "Chicago Fire", .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using `pmap_dfr()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

pmap_dfr(df, ~ bind_rows(tibble(team = ..1, points = ..4),
                         tibble(team = ..2, points = ..3)))

# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#    team                   points
#    <chr>                   <dbl>
#  1 Chicago Fire             1.73
#  2 Club de Foot Montreal    1.03
#  3 Chicago Fire             1.59
#  4 Columbus Crew            1.16
#  5 Chicago Fire             1.67
#  6 DC United                1.07
#  7 Chicago Fire             1.65
#  8 Houston Dynamo           1.10
#  9 Chicago Fire             1.25
# 10 Los Angeles Galaxy       1.50
# 11 Chicago Fire             1.52
# 12 New England Revolution   1.22
```

An identical output can be created using `pivot_wider()` twice, as also suggested by jpiversen.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(c('home', 'away'), values_to = 'team', names_to = NULL) %>%
  pivot_longer(ends_with('s'), values_to = 'points', names_to = NULL) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% 2:3) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-id)
  
# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#    team                   points
#    <chr>                   <dbl>
#  1 Chicago Fire             1.73
#  2 Club de Foot Montreal    1.03
#  3 Chicago Fire             1.59
#  4 Columbus Crew            1.16
#  5 Chicago Fire             1.67
#  6 DC United                1.07
#  7 Chicago Fire             1.65
#  8 Houston Dynamo           1.10
#  9 Chicago Fire             1.25
# 10 Los Angeles Galaxy       1.50
# 11 Chicago Fire             1.52
# 12 New England Revolution   1.22
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the pivoting in two steps:

- combining `home` and `away`
- combining `away_expected_points` and `home_expected_points`

Under is an example. I'm calling the data you provided `df`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("home", "away"), 
    names_to = "home_away", 
    values_to = "team"
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("expected_points"), 
    names_to = NULL, 
    values_to = "points"
  )
#> # A tibble: 24 x 3
#>    home_away team                  points
#>    <chr>     <chr>                  <dbl>
#>  1 home      Chicago Fire            1.03
#>  2 home      Chicago Fire            1.73
#>  3 away      Club de Foot Montreal   1.03
#>  4 away      Club de Foot Montreal   1.73
#>  5 home      Chicago Fire            1.16
#>  6 home      Chicago Fire            1.59
#>  7 away      Columbus Crew           1.16
#>  8 away      Columbus Crew           1.59
#>  9 home      Chicago Fire            1.07
#> 10 home      Chicago Fire            1.67
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

PS: if you don't want the `home_away` column you can just change the line `names_to = "home_away"` to `names_to = NULL`.